# React backgroundImage referenced in JSON file path seem weird

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My app is created with create-react-app,

Im iterating with .map through my JSON file where I store the local path to the image but I assume create-react-app changes the pathing somehow and I don't understand how.

```
const list = this.state.people.map((d, i) => { return <li
    key={i}
    className="content"
    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${d.Picture})` }}
    >
```

Above is my opening li tag where I loop out the data from my JSON file below:
The Picture in "Adam" works great and shows up on the page, however that is not where the picture is stored. I found that path in chrome dev tools so I just copy pasted.

The example below in "Bob" is the actual path to the img (from root)
I want to be able to put all my images in the images folder and store the correct path in the JSON file

```
{
  "Name": "Adam",
  "Born": 1971,
  "Picture": "/static/media/elonmusk.3489bce1.jpg"
},

{
  "Name": "Bob",
  "Born": 1999,
  "Picture": "/src/css/images/elonmusk.jpg"
},
```

[image]

Above is my folder structure, App.js is where i render the data, persons.json is where i store the file path, and images is the folder where I have the images

Answer (score 0):

Images need to be statically analysable so you need to `require` them. Please refer to this for more [background](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7015#issuecomment-217390058) info.

So with your example above, instead of using a `json`file create a `people.js` file instead like this with require statements for each image:

```
// file: people.js

const people = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Adam',
    born: 1971,
    picture: require('../path/to/image.jpg')
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    born: 1999,
    picture: require('../path/to/image2.jpg')
  }
]
```

Then you can map over this info to produce the jsx and your images will render.

```
const people = require('../path/to/people.js')

renderPeopleList () {
  return people.map(p =>
    <div key={p.id} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${p.picture})` />
  )
}
```