# how to set background images after map json file in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

In react, after I use 'map' to iterator each image, I am not able to set background images directly. After I use the 'require' keyword to solve it, but I do not know how to put the 'require' in json file or there can be some other solutions? I just want to set background images

[React backgroundImage referenced in JSON file path seem weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726844/react-backgroundimage-referenced-in-json-file-path-seem-weird?newreg=16fb6e1845b34761b7882895d27df8f0)

This is others' solution, but I do not know how to put 'require' in Json file.

```
const images = [
  {
    url: require('../../../statics/images/pfister.jpg'),
    title: 'Breakfast',
    width: '40%',
  }
];`

<span className={classes.imageSrc}
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${image.url})`,
      }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the issue you are facing.

Here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-voice-7sryi) of working code

1) `data.js` - requiring image using `require`

```
const images = [
  {
    id: 0,
    width: 230,
    height: 230,
    picture: require("../../public/download.jpeg")
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    width: 230,
    height: 230,
    picture: require("../../public/download.jpeg")
  }
];
export default images;
```

2) `index.js` - Main app utilizing the image from `data.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import images from "./data.js";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const renderImageList = () => {
    return images.map(p => (
      <div
        key={p.id}
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${p.picture})`,
          height: p.height,
          width: p.width
        }}
      />
    ));
  };
  return <div className="App">{renderImageList()}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! Do you mean that it is needed for us to add the 'require' keyword in the URL? What's more, do I have to add this  keyword in a database, like "require("../../public/download.jpeg")"