# React - dynamically set backgroundImage from JSON response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting data from my Wordpress API to display in my react app. I am trying to display the post featured image as a background-image on an element and can't seem to get it to work.

Here's an example of the JSON response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": {
    "rendered": "My First Post"
  },
  "featured_image": "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/featured.jpg"
}
```

And here's what I have tried [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726844/react-backgroundimage-referenced-in-json-file-path-seem-weird) to set the background image:

```
<div className="featured-image" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(${this.props.post.featured_image})'}}></div>
```

When I inspect the element, it appears that the JSON isn't being parsed because this is what it looks like:

```
<div class="featured-image" style="background-image: url("${this.props.post.featured_image}");"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using as string, not [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Try this:

```
<div 
   className="featured-image" 
   style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.post.featured_image})`
   }}>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, glad it was simple, won't make that mistake again xD thanks!